# How do I access csv file variable in javascript on Amazon Mechanical Turk?

Tags: javascript, html, csv, mechanicalturk

I'm a beginner to Amazon Mechanical Turk. In the project I am creating, someone can type in an input into an input field. I have a csv file that should map whatever word they input to its synonyms. If "although" was a header, I know I can do ${although} in the html to get the value  (which are the synonyms) from the csv file.

How do I access that same value in the javascript? I don't want this to be hardcoded as "although" is not the only header and there are instead hundreds of words that they can input.